# STM32 L0 wake from STOP mode with WAKEUP pin

Tags: stm32, low-power, sleep

I am attempting to wake an STM32L073RZ from stop mode using `WAKEUP_PIN_1`. I'm running MbedOS 5.11. Unfortunately throughout all of the documentation (Mbed/STM) I can't find a callback function to use. I.e. to wake from the RTC you will use the callback function: `HAL_RTC_AlarmAEventCallback(RTC_HandleTypeDef *hrtc)` but I cannot find an equivalent of this for `WAKEUP` pins.

I'm attempting to use pin `PA0` (`PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1)` as my external interrupt. I attempt to configure it according to section A.7.2 of [this](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/2f/b9/c6/34/28/29/42/d2/DM00095744.pdf/files/DM00095744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00095744.pdf) reference material, my entire program looks like this:

```
#include "mbed.h"

#define LOG(...) pc.printf(__VA_ARGS__); pc.printf("\r\n");

Serial      pc(USBTX, USBRX);

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
    LOG("Handle interrupt here...");
}

int main()
{
    pc.baud(9600);

    /* Configure PA0 as External Interrupt */
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~( GPIO_MODER_MODE0 );  // PA0 is in Input mode
    EXTI->IMR |= EXTI_IMR_IM0;              // interrupt request from line 0 not masked
    EXTI->RTSR |= EXTI_RTSR_TR0;           // rising trigger enabled for input line 0

    // Enable interrupt in the NVIC
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
    NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 0x00);

    HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFE);
}
```

I believe this is all I need to do to detect an external rising edge interrupt on PA0, but the interrupt never gets called for me. Any insight as to why is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This depends on how you configure things and how you enter STOP mode, details which are missing from your question.  Please see section 6.3 of the L0's reference manual

Comment: Hi @ChrisStratton, I've progressed further since posting the question, though I'm still unable to trigger my callback. Question updated.

Comment: Your mixture of direct register access and HAL stuff is a bit odd, and your code fragments aren't really enough to tell if your setup is complete.

Comment: I realised that the question became somewhat unruly, I've removed a lot of the extraneous garbage. The mixture between direct register access and the HAL is because I've been working/reading/copying from multiple different sources.

Comment: You really shouldn't try to generate serial output from an ISR callback.  And you should look at the *actual* ISR not just some callback that might nor might not be called depending on what the ISR does.  It's unclear if your program *ever* resumes, and if so how you know that it has.

Comment: I wouldn't normally attempt to speak UART in one, just using it as a placeholder more than anything. I've just realised that the program is hanging when I attempting to enable the IRQ: `NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);`. Also, where can I find some reference material on the actual ISR? I can't find anything else aside from the callback function. Thanks for your help so far, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: You'll find the ISR in your source code of course, if you're not sure what it is called find the table of vectors in the startup code.   Your hang could very well be caused by trying to operate the UART from within an ISR.

Comment: To leave sleep mode via the wakeup functionality you must configure the wakeup pin and not the EXTI (e.g. `HAL_PWR_EnableWakeUpPin(PWR_WAKEUP_PIN1_HIGH);`). Also remember to activate the clock for the power module : `__HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();`